# JavaScript in w3schools and codeacademy seems to be quite different - Are they two types of js

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript taught at W3Schools deals with `document.write` and so
no `console.log` is used.

In Codecademy entirely different JS is seen as compared to w3

Why is this?

Comment: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: yes, the incorrect type and correct type, respectivly

Answer (score 2):

They are the same language.

W3Schools (which is not affiliated with the W3C) is just awful. Much of their content is out of date or features bad practises.

---

There *are* multiple versions of JS (with [6/harmony/next](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) on the horizon); the language has developed over the years, so some features may not be available in older JS engines.

There are also variations in what APIs are provided by the host environment. (e.g. The `document` object is typically only found in web browsers.

Neither of these are likely to be the cause of the differences you've experienced in the tutorials though.

Comment: yes its not updates whole php n mysql are outdated